# rspec + elasticsearch test index

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, elasticsearch, rspec

I use [elasticsearch gem](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-ruby).

I have calculations, that are based on queries to ES and it's responses.

Is there a way to create a fake index for test purposes and direct all the queries to this one instead of a real ES?

Or, may be, there is more efficient way to test something, that is tightly connected to ES? I assume faking the index would slow down the test significantly, but did not think of anything better yet.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Since `elasticsearch` uses http, you can use something like [VCR](https://github.com/vcr/vcr) to record the HTTP requests.

VCR records your requests the first time you run perform them. Subsequent requests won't hit the server. Instead, VCR returns the recorded response.